# WSO2 API Manager training

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have just started exploring WSO2 API Manager.
Going through the training available at [here](http://wso2.com/training/apim-self-paced#request_training_enroll).

The Lab kit provided with the course is for WSO2AM version 1.10 whereas the latest version available on the site is 2.x. So I am setting up the environment using version 2.x

There are couple of configurations (e.g. identity.xml & secret-conf.properties) to be done which are not visible at the path specified. Has anybody faced such problem? How to correctly follow these configuration with version 2.x?

Request WSO2 team to guide on this or share updated information.

Regards,
Naishadh

Answer (score 0):

Still WSO2 might not have training material for the Latest version. But you can follow the official documentation for this. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/WSO2+API+Manager+Documentation